# finding a single maximal clique using Bron–Kerbosch

Tags: python, graph

I implemented using the networkx library the algorithm of
Bron-Kerbosch library to find all the maximal cliques in a graph G. To speed up my analysis, in very large graphs, I would like to modify this algorithm to extract only one maximal clique from graph G. Is modifying this algorithm the best solution, or are there more efficient algorithms?

```
from typing import Iterator, List
import networkx as nx

    def bron_kerbosch_1(r: list, p: list, x: list, graph: nx.classes.graph.Graph) -> Iterator[List]:
   """Basic form (i.e., without pivoting) of the Bron–Kerbosch algorithm.
                """
    if not any((p, x)):
                    yield r
                for node in p[:]:
                    r_new = r + [node]  # R ⋃ {v}
                    p_new = list(set(p).intersection(set(graph.neighbors(node))))  # P ⋂ N(v)
                    x_new = list(set(x).intersection(set(graph.neighbors(node))))  # X ⋂ N(v)
                    yield from BronKerbosch.bron_kerbosch_1(r_new, p_new, x_new, graph)
                    p.remove(node)
                    x.append(node)

G = nx.Graph()
edges = [(0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
G.add_edges_from(edges)
nodes = list(G.nodes)
maximal_cliques = list(bron_kerbosch_1(r=[], p=nodes[:], x=[], graph=G))
print(maximal_cliques)
>> [[0, 4, 1], [2, 1], [2, 3], [4, 3], [5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about performance, then you should not use python.  As an inerpretated language it runs about fifty time slower than a compiled language.

Here is C++ code to find the maximal cliques in a graph.  It can handle graphs with a hundred thousand vertices in a second or two.  For the complete application code see https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2

```
    void cPathFinder::cliques()
    {
        // working copy on input graph
        auto work = *this;

        // store for maximal clique collection
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> vclique;

        while (1)
        {
            std::vector<int> clique;

            while (work.nodeCount())
            {
                //std::cout << "work.nodeCount " << work.nodeCount() << " " << clique.size() << "\n";
                if (!clique.size())
                {
                    // start by moving an arbitrary node to the clique from the work graph
                    auto nit = work.nodes().begin();
                    clique.push_back(nit->first);
                    work.removeNode(nit->first);
                    continue;
                }
                bool found = false;

                // loop over nodes remaining in work graph
                for (auto &u : work.nodes())
                {
                    // loop over nodes in clique
                    for (int v : clique)
                    {
                        if (work.includes_link(v, u.first) ||
                            work.includes_link(u.first, v))
                        {
                            // found node in work that is connected to clique nodes.
                            // move it to clique
                            //std::cout << "add " << myGraph.name(u.first) << "\n";
                            clique.push_back(u.first);
                            work.removeNode(u.first);
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found)
                        break; // found a node to add to clique
                }
                if (!found)
                    break; // no more nodes can be added, the clique is maximal
            }

            if (!clique.size())
                break; // did not find a clique

            // add to collection of maximal cliques
            vclique.push_back(clique);
        }
```