# It is required to find a given subgraph in this graph

Tags: python, graph, combinatorics

My task is to find all occurrences of a subgraph in a graph. The conditions are such that both graphs are undirected, the subgraph is always complete.

Input parameters: two adjacency matrices, a graph and a subgraph.

Output parameters: the number of occurrences of the subgraph found in the graph and the numbers of combinations of node connections in the graph.

Also, the sequence of the arrangement of the elements of the subgraph is absolutely unimportant, in fact, the task is to find the same connections in the graph as in the subgraph.
Example: adjacency matrices are given

```
The adj_matrix graph= [
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0]
]

Subgraph
subgraph_matrix = [
[0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0]
]
```

If all this is graphically depicted on paper, it becomes clear that the subgraph forms a "triangle" type connection. There is exactly one occurrence of this subgraph in the graph and this is the connection of nodes 2, 3 and 4. Exactly ONE, it makes no sense to sort through a combination of these nodes.

Comment: You are looking for all the complete subgraphs of your input graph? That is, given a graph, you want a listing of all the maximal cliques in the graph?

Comment: If you are looking for all maximal cliques, this is a well-studied problem and there are many implementations available for that. Here's a post that contains a Python and a C++ implementation of the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm for listing out all maximal cliques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609547/finding-a-single-maximal-clique-using-bron-kerbosch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself, given an undirected graph, there are clicks of a given size.

```
def find_cliques(graph, size):
    cliques = set()
    nodes = set(graph)
    for start_node in nodes:
        subgraph = nodes.intersection(graph[start_node])
        for clique in find_subcliques(graph, [start_node], subgraph, size):
            cliques.add(tuple(sorted(clique)))
    cliques = [list(clique) for clique in cliques]
    num_cliques = len(cliques)
    return num_cliques, cliques


def find_subcliques(graph, prev_nodes, nodes, size):
    if len(prev_nodes) == size:
        yield prev_nodes
    else:
        for node in nodes:
            if all(node in graph[prev_node] for prev_node in prev_nodes):
                for clique in find_subcliques(graph, prev_nodes + [node], nodes.intersection(graph[node]), size):
                    yield clique


def adjacency_matrix_to_graph(adj_matrix):
    graph = {}
    for i in range(len(adj_matrix)):
        edges = []
        for j in range(len(adj_matrix[i])):
            if adj_matrix[i][j] == 1:
                edges.append((j + 1))
        graph[(i + 1)] = edges
    return graph


size = 3

adj_matrix = [
    [0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0]
]

graph = adjacency_matrix_to_graph(adj_matrix)
num_cliques, cliques = find_cliques(graph, size)

print(f"Number of {size}-cliques: {num_cliques}")
for i, clique in enumerate(cliques):
    print(f"Clique {i+1}: {clique}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).